# magento attribute display in product page

Tags: magento-1.9, price, product-view

i want to display a attribute just below to the price in product view page and should be dependable with price. that is I select one from attribute price should change.

Comment: So, do you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a case for **configurable products**.

For example, you create three simple products "T-Shirt M", "T-Shirt L" and "T-Shirt S" with the respective "size" attribute.

Then you create a configurable product, select "size" as configurable attribute and choose the three simple products from above as associated products. For each simple product you can choose a price difference at this step.

Comment: can you make it clear as step by step

Comment: step by step: http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-configurable.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do this from custom option also.

Ex. You can add multiple option in product custom option and set price for that. You can set it required / Non Required according to your need.